# XPath for selecting children without sub-children with same name

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an XML fragment like

```
<main>
    <sub1>
        <element>
            <sub2>
                <element>
                    <sub3/>
                </element>
            </sub2>
        </element>
    </sub1>
    <sub4>
        <sub5>
            <element>
                <sub6>
                    <element>
                        <sub7/>
                    </element>
                </sub6>
            </element>
        </sub5>
    </sub4>
    <sub8>
        <element/>
    </sub8>
</main>
```

If main is the current node, I can select all element nodes like this:

```
select=".//element"
```

This gives me 5 matches in this example. But how do I select only the first element node in the hierarchy, so the ones after sub1, sub5 and sub8? I need to ignore all elements that have another element between them and the original main node.

The number of sub nodes in between may be more than 1 or 2 as in the above example, and the main node in the example may be part of another element node above.

thanks
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
.//element[(ancestor::main|ancestor::element)[last()][self::main]]
```

**Here is a simple verification with XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each select=
   ".//element
       [(ancestor::main|ancestor::element)
                          [last()][self::main]
       ]">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
==================
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<main>
    <sub1>
        <element>
            <sub2>
                <element>
                    <sub3/>
                </element>
            </sub2>
        </element>
    </sub1>
    <sub4>
        <sub5>
            <element>
                <sub6>
                    <element>
                        <sub7/>
                    </element>
                </sub6>
            </element>
        </sub5>
    </sub4>
    <sub8>
        <element/>
    </sub8>
</main>
```

the Xpath expression is evaluated with the current node being the top node in the document, then the results of this evaluation are copied to the output, using a convenient to notice delimiter string:

```
<element>

   <sub2>

      <element>

         <sub3/>

      </element>

   </sub2>

</element>
==================
  <element>

   <sub6>

      <element>

         <sub7/>

      </element>

   </sub6>

</element>
==================
  <element/>
==================
```

**Explanation**:

The expression:

```
    .//element
       [(ancestor::main|ancestor::element)
                                     [last()]
                                        [self::main]
       ]
```

selects all descendat `element` elements of the current node the first of the two possible ancestors (upwards) `main` or `element` is `main`.

That is, there isn't an `element` that is an ancestor of the selected `element` and happens (on the way upwards) before the `main` ancestor.

To understand why `last()` is used as a predicate and not just `[1]`, we need to remember that the nearest of two ancestors is the last of them in document order.

**Do note**:

This XPath expression correctly selects all wanted `element` elements, even in the case when the current node has itself an `element` ancestor.

**An expression like the one proposed in the answer by Ian Roberts**:

```
.//element[not(ancestor::element)]
```

**selects nothing in this case**.

---

**Update**:

As noted by Michael Kay, if we further generalize this problem and allow other `main` elements to appear anywhere in the document, then the proposed expression in this answer may select "false-positives".

**Here is an updated expression (no longer a pure/standalone XPath expression, as it uses the XSLT function `current()`) that still produces the correct count in this situation**:

```
.//element
   [(ancestor::main|ancestor::element)
                      [last()][self::main]
  and
    count(current()|ancestor::main[1]) = 1
   ]"/>
```

Comment: +1 good answer. I think many of us would benefit from an explanation of the XPath expression.

Comment: @LarsH, Thanks, I added an explanation.

Comment: The answer only works if the "main" element is the only element named "main" in the tree.

Comment: All good points. I've edited my answer to handle the case where the starting node has an `element` ancestor. My approach doesn't care about the name of the starting node.

Comment: @MichaelKay, Good observation, thanks, however the OP makes it clear in the question that there is a single `main` element -- he refers to it as "the main node". Despite this, **I have updated this answer to take care of the case** where there may be many `main` elements.

Comment: many thanks for your detailed response, this for sure works as requested. I am still trying to do a better analysis of the XML file, and to parse it's overall structure, to avoid the need for this kind of construct. But it's good to know that this is possible. K.

Answer (score 2):

A possible expression would be

```
.//element[not(ancestor::element)]
```

i.e. find all "element" elements that are not enclosed (at any level) by another "element" element.

**Edit**

As noted, this expression doesn't work as is if the current (`main`) element is itself enclosed by an "element". If you're in XSLT and thus have access to the `current()` function then you could use a trick like

```
.//element[count(ancestor::element) = count(current()/ancestor::element)]
```

Which selects those elements that have the same number of enclosing "element" elements as the current "main" element has (which may be zero). Depending on your processor it may be more efficient and/or clearer to use a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="depth" select="count(ancestor::element)" />
<xsl:apply-templates select=".//element[count(ancestor::element) = $depth]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer is a bit more rigorous than Dimitre's, because it doesn't assume the absence of other elements named "main", which wasn't specified as part of the problem.

```
for $this in . return .//element[empty(ancestor::element[.>>$this])]
```

If you're in XSLT, you can use current() in place of $this.